# TListView columns order bug after windows theme change

Tags: delphi, tlistview, delphi-10-seattle

TListView's column contents become incorrect after windows theme change. I've narrowed it down to CM_RECREATE message, that's when VCL recreates TListView's window handle in response to system theme change. Below are some screenshots illustrating the problem.

**Original list view state**

[image: Initial list view state]

**Last column has been moved moved to the first position.** Everything is fine.

[image: Col moved]

After **Windows theme was changed**, the columns positions are preserved, however, the **contents are no longer correct**.

[image: Theme change]

Currently I overcome the issue by simply recreating the columns manually in my custom CM_RECREATEWND handler. Is it a bug? It it a good solution to recreate columns or is there a better way?

I'm using Delphi10 but the same behavior was observed in the previous versions as well.

Comment: Is this a behaviour that you would expect or is this behaviour documented? If not, treat it as a bug or an undocumented behaviour and report it to emba to fix or document it

Comment: Your workaround sounds good. You should submit a bug report.

Comment: @Sir Rufo, I'm pretty sure it's a bug. No one (especially users) expects wrong column contects after e.g. connecting through Remote Desktop (it also triggers the WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE and window handles recreation).

Comment: @David will do. I posted a question to make sure it's really a bug and it's not me missing something :)

Comment: Well, in some of my bug reports I ask for a fix or a documentation of that behaviour, just to make sure it will not be closed with an "works as designed". They can choose if the bug is in code or in documentation. But describing a weird behavior in the docs takes often more time than fixing ;o)

Comment: I'm not sure how they could document it as "intended behavior", as no one expects wrong list view contents after using RDP or changing windows theme. I'll post my solution to this problem later today, so that who finds this question finds a solution as well. I've reported this bug to Emb but I'm not sure when/if they fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll post my workaround in case anyone needs a quick fix for this bug. Just include this unit as a last used unit in a Form's uses list.

```
unit LVFix;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.Classes, System.UITypes, 
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TListView = class(Vcl.ComCtrls.TListView)
  strict private
    type
    TColumnRec = record
      Alignment: TAlignment;
      AutoSize: Boolean;
      Caption: String;
      ImageIndex: TImageIndex;
      MaxWidth, MinWidth, Width: TWidth;
      Tag: Integer;
      ID: Integer;
    end;
    var
      FSavedCols: TArray<TColumnRec>;
      FSavedColOrder: TArray<Integer>;
  private
    procedure SaveColumnState;
    procedure RestoreColumnState;
  protected
    procedure CMRecreate(var M: TMessage); message CM_RECREATEWND;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Winapi.CommCtrl;

{ TListView }

procedure TListView.CMRecreate(var M: TMessage);
begin
  SaveColumnState;
  inherited;
  RestoreColumnState;
end;

procedure TListView.RestoreColumnState;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Items.BeginUpdate; //lock to prevent unnecessary events firing
  try
    //recreate columns
    Columns.Clear;
    for I := 0 to High(FSavedCols) do
    begin
      with Columns.Add do
      begin
        Alignment := FSavedCols[I].Alignment;
        AutoSize := FSavedCols[I].AutoSize;
        Caption := FSavedCols[I].Caption;
        ImageIndex := FSavedCols[I].ImageIndex;
        MinWidth := FSavedCols[I].MinWidth;
        MaxWidth := FSavedCols[I].MaxWidth;
        Width := FSavedCols[I].Width;
        Tag := FSavedCols[I].Tag;
      end;
    end;
    //restore column order
    if Length(FSavedColOrder) <> 0 then
      ListView_SetColumnOrderArray(Handle, Columns.Count, PInteger(FSavedColOrder));
  finally
    Items.EndUpdate;
  end;
end;

procedure TListView.SaveColumnState;
var
  R: LongBool;
  I: Integer;
  J: Integer;
  T: TColumnRec;
begin
  //save column order
  SetLength(FSavedColOrder, Columns.Count);
  R := ListView_GetColumnOrderArray(Handle, Columns.Count, PInteger(FSavedColOrder));
  if not R then
    SetLength(FSavedColOrder, 0);
  //save original columns in original order
  SetLength(FSavedCols, Columns.Count);
  for I := 0 to Columns.Count - 1 do
  begin
    FSavedCols[I].Alignment := Columns[I].Alignment;
    FSavedCols[I].AutoSize := Columns[I].AutoSize;
    FSavedCols[I].Caption := Columns[I].Caption;
    FSavedCols[I].ImageIndex := Columns[I].ImageIndex;
    FSavedCols[I].MinWidth := Columns[I].MinWidth;
    FSavedCols[I].MaxWidth := Columns[I].MaxWidth;
    FSavedCols[I].Width := Columns[I].Width;
    FSavedCols[I].Tag := Columns[I].Tag;
    FSavedCols[I].ID := Columns[I].ID;
  end;
  for I := 0 to High(FSavedCols) - 1 do
    for J := I + 1 to High(FSavedCols) do
      if FSavedCols[J].ID < FSavedCols[I].ID then
      begin
        T := FSavedCols[I];
        FSavedCols[I] := FSavedCols[J];
        FSavedCols[J] := T;
      end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Another way is to use `JvListView` from JVCL components library - there works correctly.